# Can I run Selenium on Computer A, and see the browser in Computer B?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

Imagine I have some Selenium Project ready on Computer A. When you run this project, a new browser opens in Computer A, and connects to www.somesite.com and runs the tests..

Now, also on computer A, imagine I am running a web page, which has a button, which triggers these tests...

So when I navigate to www.ipofcomptera.com and click "Run Tests", a new browser opens in Computer A, and runs the tests...

What I want is, I either want that browser opens in Computer B ( The computer I am reaching to Computer A ) or, it may as well run in A but I want to see all the steps on my computer as well.

Hope my question clear,
Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @amey I am using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what [Selenium Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) is for!

Have fun

And please reconsider the usage of Selenium RC which is actually an undead, better use the [RemoteWebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver) instead.

Comment: Yes sorry, I actually meant RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: So my answer is what you looking for? Do you need additional info?

Comment: I am not sure yet, I will need to try it first.

Comment: I would recommend you to fork a second question, with the "remote build" issue. Grid should at least kill your selenium issue.

Comment: @KorayTugay any further Qs?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up this documents to better understand [RemoteWebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver)

In short things you would need to do

1. [Download Selenium Server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) on Computer B
2. Start the server on Computer B by doing so `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar`
3. Change your code on Computer A from 
   `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

to

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();    
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://computerB:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

And if all the required ports are open, it should all work well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I really want to do is to make a web page actually, imagine button saying "Test 1". When I click this button, I want to see in that browser, the test running. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course you can do that. You did it exactly the way you wrote in your comment. I currently use Jenkins(http://jenkins-ci.org/) for that, easy to setup. Configure a job and run your tests from there. May seem to be an overkill if you have only one test to perform.

Comment: My problem is, the developers should be able to run the tests anytime they need, so it must be kind of manual rather then automated.

Comment: Jobs on Jenkins can be made to "build"(read "test") manually as well.