# Executing the selenium tests from remote java application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We have are planning to design a system where we are planning to invoke the Selenium test that is present in a remote machine with url for testing. The selenium program should open 3 browsers for example IE, FF and Chrome and open the page and take a screenshot of it. Later These screenshots should be sent from this machine to the java application.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality ? If so could you please guide me on how to do this ?

Comment: Testing an application in a grid along with the screen shots- Is that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: i am unaware of the grid, i want my remote selenium application to take screenshot and return it to my calling application.

Comment: You have already tagged the question under selenium grid. Use the same.http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

Comment: does grid support that ?

Comment: Grid is capable of running the tests on client machines from a server machine.

Comment: @Aditya,  yes its feasible and please   [refer this](http://theautomationtester.wordpress.com/) to get started. You cannot take direct screenshot if you use RemoteWebDriver. Please [refer this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591125/how-to-get-screenshot-from-remotewebdriver-server-instead-of-local-firefoxdriver) to over come this .

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964984/can-i-run-selenium-on-computer-a-and-see-the-browser-in-computer-b/15965331#15965331

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to start a Selenium Grid/Node server on the remote machine that is configured to run all 3 browser types.  That configuration isn't easy but it involves launching the grid from a .json config file.  Then, your local program needs to just run the 3 tests either in 3 simultaneous threads, or one at a time using typical Selenium code.

Each test needs to define a Selenium Augmenter to get screenshots.  There are lots of examples on Google.